# Upscale wordpress thumbnail crop with white background

Tags: php, wordpress, image, thumbnails, crop

I want to crop my wordpress thumbnails images to 300x300px. Problem is, when I upload image 500x100 I get 300x100. I found semi solution to this problem:

```
/*  Thumbnail upscale
/* ------------------------------------ */ 
function alx_thumbnail_upscale( $default, $orig_w, $orig_h, $new_w, $new_h, $crop ){
    if ( !$crop ) return null; // let the wordpress default function handle this

    $aspect_ratio = $orig_w / $orig_h;
    $size_ratio = max($new_w / $orig_w, $new_h / $orig_h);

    $crop_w = round($new_w / $size_ratio);
    $crop_h = round($new_h / $size_ratio);

    $s_x = floor( ($orig_w - $crop_w) / 2 );
    $s_y = floor( ($orig_h - $crop_h) / 2 );

    return array( 0, 0, (int) $s_x, (int) $s_y, (int) $new_w, (int) $new_h, (int) $crop_w, (int) $crop_h );
}
add_filter( 'image_resize_dimensions', 'alx_thumbnail_upscale', 10, 6 );
```

It works, but it upscale image (makes it blury etc.) I want to add extra white space.

**1. How it works now. 2. How I want it to work.**

[image: 1. How it work now. 2. How I want it to work.]

Any ideas how to change the function to work as I want?

Comment: You can try to read this article - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/ and hit me back with further questions.

Comment: I know this article. I know how to set new thumbail sizes etc. I don't see there an option to do what I want :) I need a function that will "rework" how crop works in all thumbnail sizes.